# Iteratively write rows of pandas dataframe to a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
     state  year  candidate  forecast_prob result  winflag
0  Alabama  2008   Sessions           1.00    Win        1
1  Alabama  2008    Figures           0.00   Lose        0
2  Alabama  2010     Shelby           1.00    Win        1
3  Alabama  2010     Barnes           0.00   Loss        0
4   Alaska  2008     Begich           1.00    Win        1
5   Alaska  2008    Stevens           0.00   Lose        0
6   Alaska  2010     Miller           0.71   Lose        0
7   Alaska  2010  Murkowski           0.21    Win        1
8   Alaska  2010    McAdams           0.08   Loss        0
9  Arizona  2010   Glassman           1.00    Win        1
```

I've turned this into a Pandas dataframe. How can I write every single row to another CSV file where result = `Win`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new dataframe

`new_df = df[df["result"] == "Win"]`

And you can write it to csv.

`new_df.to_csv("new_df.csv")`